# Using execute command in Page Objects in Nightwatch JS

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, frontend, nightwatch.js, pageobjects

I have a problem with implementing Page Object in Nightwatch. Let's say that I have a login scenario. I need to scroll to the element - I'm using for thar execute function.

```
module.exports = {  
   'Login' : function (browser) {
    browser.url(this.launchUrl)
       .setValue('input[name=username]', 'admin')
       .setValue('input[name=password]', 'password')
       .execute(function () {
            document.querySelector('input[type=submit]').scrollIntoView();
        }, [])
       .click('input[type=submit]');
    browser.end();
    }
}
```

I'd like to refactor this login code into Page Object like that

```
module.exports = {  
  url: function() {
    return this.api.launchUrl;
  },
  commands: [scrolling],
  elements: {
    usernameField: {
      selector: 'input[name=username]'
    },
    passwordField: {
      selector: 'input[name=password]'
    },
    submit: {
     selector: 'input[type=submit]'
  }
  }
};
```

I'd like to 'hide' also this execute command and pack it into commands, like that:

```
var scrolling = {
  scroll: function(){
    return this.execute(function () {
      document.querySelector(input[type=submit]').scrollIntoView();
    }, []);
  }
};
```

Unfortunately it seems that execute command doesn't work with Page Object.

How I can overcome this issue with executing JavaScript code when I want to use Page  Object? How can I encapsulate it?

Comment: Just a note that maybe can be helpful. In my cases `execute` just works when it is passed as a string. e.g. `.execute('document.querySelector('input[type=submit]').scrollIntoView();')`

Comment: But do you use it in the main test file (my first piece of code) or you use page object like here: http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#page-objects ?  execute() can contain both function or string http://nightwatchjs.org/api/execute.html

Comment: I checked suggested string but it didn't solve a problem.

Comment: There is a list of accessible methods in page object from the api documentation: 
https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/wiki/Page-Object-API#enhanced-page-object-command-api-methods

Answer (score 1):

The answer was very simple 
1) There was a quotation mark missing in a selector.
2) Using execute() in Object Pattern it is needed to run it using this.api :

```
this.api.execute(function () {
             document.querySelector('input[type=submit]').scrollIntoView();
          }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer

```
ForthStCheck:function(){
   this.api.execute('scrollTo(0,500)')
   this.waitForElementVisible('@forthStationPlayBtn',5000)
}
```

Comment: Will this only work for a specific  sized page?

Also can you explain why this code excerpt works?